# How can you dynamically resolve or introspect variables

Tags: go, dynamic, reflection

Is there a way to resolve or introspect a variable identified from a string of its name?

For instance, if I have a string value `strVal := "s"` that corresponds to the name of a variable such as `var s string` which is in the same function
's scope, can I dynamically look up the value of the `s` variable?

I know if these were fields of a struct, I could use reflection, but for my use case, I am dealing with locally scoped variables that are not part of a struct or map.

Comment: I think the efficient way to do this is to keep pointers of these local variables into a global registry var (a map[string]interface) and implement on top of it some concurrency-safe accessor functions or methods. This kinda solution was adopted by many libraries... I think is the most idiomatic / promoted one

Comment: "a random variable in golang" - Can you clarify how you imagine identifying the random variable? From a string of its name, for example?

Comment: Yes, from a string of its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you cloud extract this information from a struct.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

)

type Article struct {
    Id    int   
    Title string
    Price float32
    Authors []string    
}

func main() {

    article := Article{}

    e := reflect.ValueOf(&article).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < e.NumField(); i++ {
        name := e.Type().Field(i).Name
        varType := e.Type().Field(i).Type
        value := e.Field(i).Interface()
        fmt.Printf("%v %v %v\n", name, varType, value)
    }
}
```

Example:

https://play.golang.org/p/vWkRzpvWKYn

Comment: This is as good as you can get in Go, as far as I can tell. Thanks!

Comment: They discuss a lot of new upcoming features for go2 on Github. Maybe you could create an issue -> https://github.com/golang/go/labels/Go2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to analyze while runtime a variable then you could use a debugger like delve

Ref: https://github.com/go-delve/delve

Comment: Is it possible to programmatically (at run time) use delve to identify the value of variables by name?

Comment: This is super strange your idea but maybe you could directly call a delve API to get this information but I think this isn't a best practice -> https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2018/04/30/debugging-containerized-go-applications/

Comment: Yeah, it seems like I would be swimming upstream. My use case is that I want to enable metaprogramming similar to `Eval`, but it seems this is not easy, and I should just avoid the situation entirely.

Comment: You could maybe fork some concepts and code fragments of this interpreter-> https://github.com/containous/yaegi

Answer (score -1):

> [I]f I have a string value strVal := "s" that corresponds to the name of a var s string in the same scope, can I dynamically look up the value of s?

No. A dead simple No.